# swift 3: How to add UISlider?

Tags: ios, swift, slider, avaudioplayer, core-audio

I have `ViewController` with `AVAudioPlayer`. Now I have this code

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!
var index = 0
var timer: Timer?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if index == 0{

       let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "1", withExtension: "mp3")!

        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            //audioPlayer.play()
            //play(sender:AnyObject.self as AnyObject)

        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func slide(_ slider: UISlider) {
    audioPlayer.currentTime = TimeInterval(slider.value)
}

@IBAction func play(sender: AnyObject) {
    if !audioPlayer.isPlaying{
        audioPlayer.play()
        // **** The line below is the new line ****
        timer = Timer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateSlider), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        RunLoop.main.add(timer!, forMode: .commonModes)
    } else {
        audioPlayer.pause()
        playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "pause.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        timer?.invalidate()
    }
}

func updateSlider(_ timer: Timer) {
    slider.value = Float(audioPlayer.currentTime)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
```

I want to add UISlider that change scrub through the audio file. How to do it?

Comment: Do you want to change the volume or scrub through the audio file?

Comment: @0x6368 I want to change scrub through the audio file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to add a new IBAction from the slider to make sure your class gets notified when the sliders value changes (Look for "Responding to User Interaction" here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uislider#2557863)

In this event handler you have to set the audios current time

```
@IBAction func slide(_ slider: UISlider) {
    audioPlayer.currentTime = TimeInterval(slider.value)
}
```

To make sure the slider updates its value according to the current time, you have to add a timer when you start the player that calls a custom method which updates the sliders value.

```
@IBAction func play(sender: AnyObject) {
    if !audioPlayer.isPlaying{
        audioPlayer.play()
        // **** The line below is the new line ****
        timer = Timer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateSlider), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .commonModes)
    } else {
        audioPlayer.pause()
        playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "pause.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Afterwards you have to create the method which updates the sliders value

```
func updateSlider(_ timer: Timer) {
    slider.value = Float(audioPlayer.currentTime)
}
```

Then you have to set the sliders maximum value

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if index == 0{

       let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "1", withExtension: "mp3")!

        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            // **** These two lines below are new ****
            slider.maximumValue = Float(audioPlayer.duration)
            slider.value = 0.0
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

And finally you have to create a property below your IBOutlets which holds the timer

```
var timer: Timer?
```

Comment: Be careful with possible retain cycles though, that repeating `timer` retains `self`, and `self` seems to be retaining the `timer`. The `invalidate()` should break the cycle but leaving the screen while the audio is being reproduced might require some clean up.

Comment: It is work. But when I scrubbing my slider is freezing . How to fix it?

Comment: Edit: I've updated [0x6368](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1213411/0x6368)'s answer to include the `timer` in the run loop common modes, in order to fix the freezing of the slider when scrolling.

Comment: I have issue `Class ‘ViewController’ has no initializers` how to fix it?

Comment: I think you should add a "?" to the timer:
`var timer: Timer?`
Otherwise it is not allowed to be `nil`

Comment: I update code in question, please check. When I scribbling slider track starts to play again. How to fix it?

Comment: I updated the answer. You have to set the sliders maximum value as well